# Want to understand how to configure STM32 CAN filters, what calulation needed

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus

I am trying to configure `CAN` filters as per my need which is, I want to send 10 different ID's and apart from them. I don't want to receive anything on CAN BUS.
ID's are -

```
0x18FCC800
0x18FD0700
0x18FD0900
0x18FD7C00
0x18FDC200
0x18FD9503
0x1CFC4221
0x1CFC4233
0x18FE5600
0x18FEFC00
```

I don't understand how to configure these filters, so I can manage to change them if needed for more or the same. If anyone can help me how to calculate these configurations, as I did read some posts they show values but doesn't elaborate how and why. so please help me out here.

```
sFilterConfig.FilterBank            = 0;
sFilterConfig.FilterMode            = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
sFilterConfig.FilterScale           = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh          = ((ext_id<<3) >>16) &0xffff;  //Set the high byte of the identifier register.
sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow           = (uint16_t)(ext_id<<3) | CAN_ID_EXT;   //Set the low byte of the identifier register
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh      = (mask>>16)&0xffff;
sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow       = mask&0xffff;
sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment  = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
sFilterConfig.FilterActivation      = ENABLE;
//sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank    = 0;
```

Comment: Where are the variable declarations of `ext_id` and `mask`?

Comment: well i found a solution related to above. The thing i understood is, we have to find the common bits in ID's and make them 1 which gives you a value so CAN hardware can decide these are the bits we need to pass. apart from this if anyone need the calculation please let me know i'll share here.

Comment: Well yeah, that's how it works... you typically have an "acceptance mask" which sets the rough idea of what parts you are interested in, then the "message filter" which is typically some bitwise OR of all valid identifiers. There used to be a neat online calculator somewhere which supported calculations for a lots of different controllers. Most of the time, filtering is more trouble than it's worth. Typically I only bother with it when designing simple nodes that should just listen to very few identifiers. Modern CAN controllers with mailboxes is a much better solution.